# Guys ,How make a popup notification for apps that i blocked with Windows Firewall ,to remind me that i blocked them when i Open the Application

Tags: windows, notifications, firewall

How make a popup notification  for apps that i blocked with Windows Firewall ,to remind me that i blocked them when i Open the Application

Ex:Windows Store
i blocked windows store because its background updates consume my alot of data.

but when i needed to access windows store i always forget that i  blocked windows store  with firewall and keep messing with my router

so how how enable this kind of  feature

i want to popup a notification like this when i open windows store
"Windows store is Blocked with Windows firewall Please Unblock the Firewall Rule to Gain access to Windows Store"

I want to know is there any extensions or something Like Glasswire have that kind of Feature ,
or how programme a script

Comment: Windows Firewall is not designed to show an UI dialog (except for first time). You may better check for a desktop firewall tool that has an own UI

Comment: thanx but how can someone programme a feature like that i need to know the progrmming design

Comment: First if all you need a programming language you are familiar with and the check if you can find open source application firewalls for that language.